# Como generar Divs dinamicos en asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, bootstrap, asp

Estoy trabajando con algunos diseños en [asp](/questions/tagged/asp), quiero ahorrarme la creación de x numero de paginas ASP, cabe mencionar que estoy trabajando con [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap) y [masterpages](/questions/tagged/masterpages) donde ya definí el `header` y `footer` pero en la pagina (**default**) donde estoy trabajando tengo dos secciones (`div`) uno de las listas y otro del contenedor que va a cambiar según el enlace en la lista.

No se si debería crear todos los `div` dentro de la pagina **default** y ocultarlos y mostrarlos con [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), supongo que hay mejores formas para no crear muchas paginas y agregar todos los `div` en la misma pagina ya que son como 40 aproximadamente.

```
<li>
   <a href="#">lista 1</a>
</li>
<li>
   <a href="#">lista 2</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">lista 3</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Si ver tal o cual `div` depende de un suceso dinamico en el navegador, esta bien que uses javascript, pero si no, es recomendable que directamente lo limites en el servidor

```
 @if (PasaTalCosa) {
     @Html.Partial("Div1")
 }
```

Como ves en el ejemplo, tambien podes poner cada uno de los `divs` en su propio partial, por las dudas que necesites usarlo en diferentes acciones.

Comment: Gracias por responder @Eduardo

Answer (score 0):

Crear elementos  desde el código de servidor de tu página .aspx es muy sencillo, en tu .aspx.cs:

```
private void CrearItems()
{

 // Crear elemento div genérico
 HtmlGenericControl item = new HtmlGenericControl("div");

 // Creamos los elementos de la lista de forma dinámica
 foreach (var elemento in tuColeccion)
 {                
     // Establecer atributos necesarios
     // item.Attributes.Add("class", "item");
     // item.Id
     // item.InnerHtml
     // etc...

     // Añadir elemento div al elemento contenedor
     contenedor.Controls.Add(item)    
 }   

}
```

En tu .aspx sólo necesitas definir un control contenedor al que se añadirán los `<div>`.
Puede ser un asp.net web server control:

```
<asp:Panel ID= "contenedor"  runat = "server"></asp:Panel>
```

o bien, un html server control:

```
<div id="contenedor" class="contenedor" runat="server"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Lo que necesitas aqui es hacer una SPA (Single Page Application). Haz visto **Angular**??

Puedes ver como trabaja este ejemplo: http://codepen.io/eladrin201/pen/NPxEow para hacerte una idea.